# Divide by Zero Error Encountered when using multiple SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, isnull

I have created the following query

```
SELECT LPORGNAME
,SUM(TOTALNoOFTRANSFERS) as TOTAL
,SUM(TReads) AS TReads
,ISNULL(ROUND(ISNULL(SUM(TReads),0)/CAST(SUM(TOTALNoOFTRANSFERS)AS FLOAT)*100,2),0)
FROM T_SPID_TRANSFER_IVSO
WHERE DM_FISC_YEAR = '2014-15'
GROUP BY LPORGNAME, DM_FISC_YEAR
ORDER BY LPORGNAME, DM_FISC_YEAR
```

But I am running into the divieded by zero error, as you can see i have tried to attempt a ISNULL way, but this doesnt work. How would i go about fixing this?

**EDIT** The TOTALNoOFTRANSFERS is a SUM Column that does not allow NULLS so there for it will always be 0

**EDIT** Found a simple way to avoid all the 0's. Adding an WHERE TOTALNoOFTRANSFERS > 0, avoids all the 0's all together

Comment: Is the Sum of TOTALNoOFTRANSFERS a Null?   This could be your problem.  (Your inner IsNull is acting on the numerator, not the denominator.  Your outer IsNull is too late.  You will need to check the denominator.)

Comment: @DeadZone Division by `NULL` should return `NULL`.  Only division by an actual zero value should result in a division by zero error.

Comment: The TOTALNoTransfers is ANOTHER SUM within the table(for example col1+col2+col3). But within this query i have to get the percentage of columnA within this TOTALNoTransfers this column can have a 0 if col1+2+3 = 0.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you do

```
SUM(TReads) / SUM(TOTALNoOFTRANSFERS)*100
```

which could be for instance

```
3 / 0
```

Dividing by zero can't be calculated. Think about what should be displayed then and make an exception. Like this

```
case when SUM(TOTALNoOFTRANSFERS) = 0
     then 0
     else SUM(TReads) / SUM(TOTALNoOFTRANSFERS)*100
end
```